# Blockwise RSA encryption using Bouncy Castle in java

Tags: java, c#, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle

In C#, I am encrypting the text data by doing something like below (please notice that I am encrypting the data in chunks (blocks):

```
        public string EncryptData(string publicKey, string data)
        {
            try
            {
                var bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                int srclen = bytesToEncrypt.Length;

                //Prepare encryption engine
                var encryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

                //Initialize Key
                using (var txtreader = new StringReader(publicKey))
                {
                    var keyParameter = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();
                    encryptEngine.Init(true, keyParameter);
                }

                //Encrypt in loop
                byte[] complete = new byte[0];
                int src_block_size = encryptEngine.GetInputBlockSize();
                for (int idx = 0; idx < srclen; idx += src_block_size)
                {
                    int data_len = srclen - idx;
                    if (data_len > src_block_size)
                    {
                        data_len = src_block_size;
                    }

                    var encryptedChunk = encryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToEncrypt, idx, data_len);
                    complete = CombineByteArrays(complete, encryptedChunk);
                }

                var finalString = Convert.ToBase64String(complete);
                return finalString;
            }
            catch (InvalidCipherTextException)
            {
                //catch exception
            }
        }
```

Now, I need to do provide the same encryption logic to some java guy (I am not at all familiar with java). Right now this is how they are doing it:

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] text, PublicKey key) throws Exception
    {
        byte[] cipherText = null;
        //
        // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

        // encrypt the plain text using the public key
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text);
        return cipherText;
    }
```

So, sometimes decryption (which is happening on .Net based server) fails with error "input too large for RSA cipher." So I am suspecting that it could be because of the difference in logic of encrypting and decrypting the data (encryption is happening on java based client with the logic posted above and decryption is happening on .Net based client with below logic):

```
public string DecryptData(string privateKey, string base64Data)
        {
            try
            {
                var bytesToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);
                AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;
                //var internalEngine = new RsaEngine();
                var decryptEngine = new RsaEngine(); //No paddind. We'll hunt the data inside packets
                using (var txtreader = new StringReader(privateKey))
                {
                    keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();
                    decryptEngine.Init(false, keyPair.Private);
                }

                //Loop por todo el bloque y saca data
                byte[] complete = new byte[0];
                int blockSize = decryptEngine.GetInputBlockSize();
                for (int chunkPosition = 0; chunkPosition < bytesToDecrypt.Length; chunkPosition += blockSize)
                {
                    //int chunkSize = Math.Min(blockSize, bytesToDecrypt.Length - ((chunkPosition / blockSize) * blockSize));
                    int chunkSize = bytesToDecrypt.Length - chunkPosition;
                    if (chunkSize > blockSize)
                    {
                        chunkSize = blockSize;
                    }

                    var decryptedChunk = decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToDecrypt, chunkPosition, chunkSize);

                    //the actual decrypted data is in the middle, locate it!
                    int idxFirstZero = -1;
                    int outlen = decryptedChunk.Length;
                    int idxNextZero = (int)outlen;
                    for (int i = 0; i < outlen; i++)
                    {
                        if (decryptedChunk[i] == 0)
                        {
                            if (idxFirstZero < 0)
                            {
                                idxFirstZero = i;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                idxNextZero = i;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    var totalSizeToCopy = idxNextZero - idxFirstZero - 1;
                    Array.Resize(ref complete, complete.Length + totalSizeToCopy);
                    int dstOffset = complete.Length - totalSizeToCopy > 0 ? complete.Length - totalSizeToCopy : 0;
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(decryptedChunk, idxFirstZero + 1, complete, dstOffset, totalSizeToCopy);
                }

                var finalString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(complete).Trim('\0');
                return finalString;
            }
            catch (InvalidCipherTextException)
            {

            }
        }
```

So as you can see I am decrypting the data in blocks. So my question is how can we do the encryption in java (using bouncy castle) blockwise (the way I am doing in .Net in the very first code snippet in the post)?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a learning exercise? If not, please throw away your code and implement proper [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). RSA should not be used as a block cipher. You should encrypt your message with AES and encrypt the random AES key with RSA.

Comment: *"... I am encrypting the data [with RSA] in chunks (blocks) ..."* - ***IF*** you are applying RSA to each block, then that's called operating RSA in ECB mode. The [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) specifically warns against the practice.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a common operation as for large data (and even smaller data) usually hybrid encryption is used, where a mode of operation (such as CBC) of a symmetric cipher is used to encrypt larger data object.

As far as I know there is no direct way to request the maximum input size of RSA / PKCS#1 from the `Cipher` instance.

However, that's not much of an issue as you can calculate this yourself given the RSA key size. And this key size is the same as the size of the modulus (in bytes):

1. calculate the modulus size in bytes: `(keysize - 1) / Byte.SIZE + 1` or, if the keysize is a multiple of 8 (as usual), just `keysize / Byte.SIZE` of course;
2. subtract 11 bytes from the result (for PKCS#1 v1.5 padding);

to get to the keysize, just cast your key to an `RSAPublicKey` and then call `getModulus()` followed by `bitLength()` on the resulting `BigInteger`.

---

Note that sending ciphertext without integrity protection (e.g. a signature) is not considered very secure. PKCS#1 may also fall victim to padding oracle attacks, especially when use in transport mode security. RSA / OAEP would be a better choice, used for hybrid encryption (as RSA /OAEP [will store even less](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100/1172)).